# How to refer to a single element of a mapped array to render a View

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I've got an array of object. I mapped it to render it like a list with a label and an icon button.
I need to show another View below the element of the row when I hit the button.

The array of object is a let variable. I would have like to make it as a state (because of the re-rendering when a function setState is executed), but I need it as a let variable because they are datas coming from a navigation route

My idea was to add a flag in every object of the array to indicate when the View has to be rendered. This would have been false at the beginning and true when I hit the button, but nothing happen. While if don't use a flag when I hit the button, the View is rendered in every row

```
state={
   visible:false
}

getNewView = (item) => {
        if (this.state.visible && item.showViewBelow)
            return (
                <View>
                    <HiddenViewComponent/>
                </View>
            )
};

btnHandler = (item) => {
   item.showViewBelow = true;
   this.setState({visible:true})
}


render(){
   const {navigation} = this.props;
   const arrayNav = navigation.getParam('data', '');

   let array = [
            {
                id:'0',
                label: arrayNav.label1,
                showViewBelow: false
            },
            {
                id:'1',
                label: arrayNav.label2,
                showViewBelow: false
            },
            {
                id:'2',
                label: arrayNav.label3,
                showViewBelow: false
            }
   ]
return(
  <View>
     array.map((item, key)=> { return

         <View key = {key} style={{marginHorizontal: 25}}>

              <Text>{item.label}</Text>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.btnHandler(item)}>
                 <Image source=(blablabla)/>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              {this.getNewView(item)}

         </View>)

     )}
  </View>
)
 }
```

So, when i click in a row of the list, I want a new view to be showed below THIS row.

I tried to switch to true the flag in one of the object and leave it to false in the others. It works fine on that line! When I click the button in that row, the new view is correctly rendered below that row.

I tried also using a Flatlist and put some extradata with a state variable to be updated with a setState after the return of the new view. (just to try to re-render the page).

Still, I tried to put this.forceUpdate() in the getNewView method. Nothing happen. Nothing is rendered

So I think the problem is I don't re-render the whole screen, because having the object as let variable, this doesn't happen.

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create method in constant utility to define defaultArray like

```
getDefaultArray(arrayNav){

    return [
        {
            id:'0',
            label: arrayNav.label1,
            showViewBelow: false
        },
        {
            id:'1',
            label: arrayNav.label2,
            showViewBelow: false
        },
        {
            id:'2',
            label: arrayNav.label3,
            showViewBelow: false
        }
   ];

}
```

In your component code

```
import Constants from "./Constants"

ComponentDidMount(){

    const {navigation} = this.props;
    const arrayNav = navigation.getParam('data', '');

    this.state={
        visible:false,
        array = Constants.getDefaultArray(arrayNav);
    }
}

getNewView = (item) => {
        if (this.state.visible && item.showViewBelow)
            return (
                <View>
                    <HiddenViewComponent/>
                </View>
            )
};

btnHandler = (item, index) => {

   const {navigation} = this.props;
   const arrayNav = navigation.getParam('data', '');

   let newData = Constants.getDefaultArray(arrayNav);
   newData[index].showViewBelow = true;
   this.setState({visible:true , array:newData})
}

render(){

    return(
      <View>
         this.state.array.map((item, key)=> { return

             <View key = {key} style={{marginHorizontal: 25}}>

                  <Text>{item.label}</Text>

                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.btnHandler(item,key)}>
                     <Image source=(blablabla)/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  {this.getNewView(item)}

             </View>)

         )}
      </View>
    )
 }
```

Comment: Should I change showViewBelow without a setState? I mean in btnHandler function

Comment: No. You have to change **showViewBelow** with setState(). You have to find the index which presses and then search item by index in state and change the state so it will reflect on rendering view.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how to do it? I mean how to do the setState function? How can i access to array[i].showViewBelow once I have found the index?

Comment: Ok, so, the thing is that I can't declare a car/let variable into the class. It has to be above the export default class. Also, declaring the state like that (with constructor(props...), I got an error when I use the state (I think from typescript). For example if I do this.state.visible, I got Property 'visible' does not exist in type ReadOnly<{}>

Comment: The Property 'visible' does not exist in type ReadOnly<{}> is always there if I use this.state={a:1, b:2}

Comment: Are you using this kind of component **export class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState>** ?

Comment: export default class MyClass extends Component{}. I made it 'compile' using state={} instead of this.state={}, and using setState({array: Constants.getDefaultArray(arrayNav);}) in a componentWillMount. Doin'it in componentDidMount returns me an empty list. But still doesn't work! Nothing is showed when I click on the button

Comment: Solved! The problem was I was not calling well the onPress function in the Touchable Opacity component. Thanks man!